# How to pretty print a hierarchical list?

Tags: python, list

I am very new to Python, and in the University, our teacher gave us the following problem:

He gave us the following list:

`[ '1,2,3,4', '2,5,6', '3,7,8', '4,9' ]`

It is supposed to go like this: 1 is the supervisor of 2, 3, 4 and 2 is the supervisor of 5, 6 etc
So, our teacher wants us to write a program that pretty-prints the graph like this:

```
1

....2

........5

........6

....3

........7

........8

....4

........9
```

Problem is, I cannot understand how to do this...
Any help or ideas please?

Comment: Hi there! What have you tried? What do you know about Python so far?

Comment: Please atleast try something and let people know you tried. Ask for help for specific purpose(if you don't understand something). This is not the place to complete your assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this solution. At least it works with the example you gave. Please ask questions if you need any explanations of the code below: the comments should guide you.

```
lst_string = ['1,2,3,4', '2,5,6', '3,7,8', '4,9']
# first, transform your list into a nested list

# create an empty list
lst_nested = list()

for seq_string in lst_string:
    to_list = list(seq_string)  # the first list looks like ["1", ",", "2", ",", "3", ",", "4']
    to_list = to_list[0::2]  # this removes the "," inputs
    to_list = list(map(int, to_list))  # this transforms ["1", "2", "3"] into [1,2,3]
    lst_nested.append(to_list)

# define the list of first elements
first_elements = list()
for lst in lst_nested:
    first_elements.append(lst[0])

# prepare the output
tab = "...."

def fill_in(seq, idx_tab):
    # always displays the first element
    output = ""
    output += tab * idx_tab
    output += str(seq[0])
    output += "\n"

    for intgr in seq[1:]:
        if intgr in first_elements: 
            # call recursively function fill_in with the corresponding seq
            output += fill_in(lst_nested[first_elements.index(intgr)], idx_tab + 1)

        else:
            output += tab * (idx_tab + 1)
            output += str(intgr)
            output += "\n"

    return output

print(fill_in(lst_nested[0], 0))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You gave me a great idea how to build my own solution! I was not using +=, instead I was going with = only...